# Disable auto load media resource

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How disable auto load media resource in selenium(chromedriver)? Now i finded how disable load images(code below)

```py
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs={"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2 }
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

add "profile.managed_default_content_settings.media_stream": 2 don`t work

Comment: What is your usecase exactly?

Comment: I load a some page(in local intranet) by selenium, and i need to reduce traffic. I can disable load ccs("profile.managed_default_content_settings.stylesheets": 2,), image("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2), js ("profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript": 2,) but can`t disable load media type